# MouseDragged event is too slow

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

[image]

I have a problem with Java Swing. In short words, I have some lines (Line2D) over a JPanel. The lines are arranged in a Vector. When I move the mouse on a line, I create a little rectangle, check if it intersects the line, and search the line in the Vector.

Once I have located the line in the vector, I would want to change it.

If I start to drag the mouse on a point on the line, I would want to split the line in two lines. To do this, I repaint in mouseDragged event.

It soon becomes clear with the image attached

My problem is that if I drag speedly with the mouse, the repaint method seems not to follow the changes, while If I drag slowly it works perfectly.

By mistake I changed the function that intercepts the line, and the problem did not present itself, but there were some exceptions and the GUI doesn't work fine.

Here the code of the function I have mentioned:

```
public int getTransition(int x, int y) {
  int HIT_BOX_SIZE = 5;
  int boxX = x - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;
  int boxY = y - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;
  int width = HIT_BOX_SIZE;
  int height = HIT_BOX_SIZE;
  for (int i = 0; i < transition_list.size(); i++) {
    if (transition_list.get(i).transition.intersects(boxX, boxY, width, height))
      return i;
    else if (transition_list.get(i).spezzata == true)
      if (transition_list.get(i).segmento.intersects(boxX, boxY, width, height))
        return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Consider creating and posting a valid [mcve] or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Please check out the details of this useful tool in the links as the techniques will be helpful for your own debugging attempts.

Comment: This sounds more of a Thread problem. Have you tried putting the `getTransition` method in another thread?

Comment: `My problem is that if I drag speedly with the mouse, the repaint method seems not to follow the changes, while If I drag slowly it works perfectly.` - a MouseEvent does NOT generate an event for every pixel the mouse is moved when the drag speed is fast. So (I'm guessing)  your logic will need to account for the fact that the distance travelled between events could be greater than 1 pixel in either the x or y direction.

Comment: @skw I have already tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: @camickr I wish that when I drag the mouse the two lines are fluently repaint although quickly drag, do you have any idea?

Comment: @DanieleLoVetere, no I don't have any ideas because you haven't posted your MCVE/SSCCE like you were asked to do 11 hours ago. So I can't execute your code to see the behaviour. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). I don't notice any lag when trying to draw/resize the rectangle.